# Хакер получил ID сессии через куки , что он может сделать?

Tags: cookie, безопасность, сессия, взлом

Как хакер может получить данные куки и что он может сделать имея ключ сессии? Какая разница куки или сессия если есть возможность украсть куки а затем использовать id сессии и получить необходимые данные?

Comment: Что конкретно сервер позволит, то и сможет.

Answer (score 1):

Хакер может, например, прослушать сеть, притвориться на время сервером.

Имея ключ сессии, можно делать то, что может делать пользователь.

Куки можно использовать для хранения ключа сессии.

Eсли данные хранить в куки они будут балтаться туда-сюда по сети, если в сессии на сервере -- лежать на сервере. У ключа объем меньше.

Ключ сессии может быть и не в куки, а в sessionStorage, например.

Answer (score 0):

Приведу отрывок из [статьи](https://www.google.com/amp/s/xakep.ru/2012/10/04/safe-session-token/%3Famp).

> Куки используются в HTTP для аутентификации сессий, чтобы распознать конкретного юзера в общей массе. Однако куки не гарантируют совершенно никакой безопасности, потому что создавались не для этого и передаются по Сети в открытом виде. Кто угодно может взять чужие куки и залогиниться под чужим аккаунтом, даже не зная пароля. Существует масса простых утилит для перехвата чужих куки в открытых сетях, например в бесплатном Wi-Fi-хотспоте (взять хотя бы Firesheep и DroidSheep).

Comment: Так получается что нету разницы хранить данные в куки или в сессии так как куки могут украсть (тогда нету разницы id там или пароль) и в любом случае данные похитят. Хакер может выдавать себя за пользователя используя id сессии.Какой смысл во всем этом?

Comment: https можно использовать